# excel vba select right down triangle

Tags: vba, excel, select

I have a question about selecting down triangle.
I know I can select the diagonal by this code:

```
Sub SelectDiagonal()
a = Selection.Row()
b = Selection.Column()
c = Selection.Rows.Count
d = Selection.Columns.Count
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Cells(a + c - 1, b)
 For i = 1 To c - 1
  Set Rng = Union(Rng, Cells(a + c - 1 - i, b + i))
   Next
Rng.Select
End Sub
```

However, I want to select all down triangle.
What I want is to select yellow cells like following pic.

[image]

I tried this code:

```
Sub SelectDownTriangle()
a = Selection.Row()
b = Selection.Column()
c = Selection.Rows.Count
d = Selection.Columns.Count

  For i = 1 To c - 1
     For j = 1 To i
     Cells(a + i, b + d - j).Select
     Next
  Next
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work.

Any help? Thanks

**[Edit]**
With @Vityata's answer, I edit the code:

```
Sub SelectDownTriangle()
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, d As Long
    Dim i As Long

    a = Selection.Row()
    b = Selection.Column()
    c = Selection.Rows.Count
    d = Selection.Columns.Count

    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim Rng     As Range

    Set Rng = Cells(a + c - 1, b + 1)

    For i = 1 To c - 1
        Set Rng = Union(Rng, Cells(a + c - 2 - i, b + i + 1))
        If Cells(a + c - 2 - i, b + i + 1).Column > lastCol Then
            lastCol = Cells(a + c - 2 - i, b + i).Column
        End If
    Next

    Dim colCounter      As Long
    Dim myCell          As Range

    For Each myCell In Rng
        For colCounter = myCell.Column To lastCol
            Cells(myCell.Row, colCounter).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        Next colCounter
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

However, the output is not correct.
[image]

What I want is:
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to select the cells? Do you plan on doing anything with them? You could easily loop through that range and add cells with yellow background to another range?

Comment: Actually all cells do not have color. Therefore I want to select them and add color. Also, sometimes, I want to delete them at one time.

Answer (score 1):

With the usage of your code, you need a loop, that loops for every cell in the `rng` to the last column possible and filling it with color:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectDiagonal()
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, d As Long
    Dim i As Long

    a = Selection.row()
    b = Selection.Column()
    c = Selection.Rows.Count
    d = Selection.Columns.Count

    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim Rng     As Range

    Set Rng = Cells(a + c - 1, b)

    For i = 1 To c - 1
        Set Rng = Union(Rng, Cells(a + c - 1 - i, b + i))
        If Cells(a + c - 1 - i, b + i).Column > lastCol Then
            lastCol = Cells(a + c - 1 - i, b + i).Column
        End If
    Next

    Dim colCounter      As Long
    Dim myCell          As Range

    For Each myCell In Rng
        For colCounter = myCell.Column To lastCol
            Cells(myCell.row, colCounter).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        Next colCounter
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: it seemes correct. However, I don't want the diagonal, just below diagonal (not `A10`, `B9`, `C8`, `D7`, `E6`....)